# Filter Rows based on rows and column condition in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to filter rows from a table that is akin to row-level security. I have another table that lists the access level for certain users. When applying a user level filter where the conditions are based on multiple columns.

The first table is as follows, this list the users and access to TGs that would require access from the second table -

[image]

So ID 1234 has access to all TG i.e. A, B and C. 4321 has two TGs i.e B and C

The second table has Member information where each member has a Reg and TG assigned -

[image]

So, when based on the condition of the ID entered the output should be limited to the TG access and Reg.

If we enter the ID as 1234, the output should be the following -

[image]

Similarly, if the ID is 4321 the output should be -

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I managed to use the query by Akina. It worked in MySQL. I tried the same in Hive but needed to modify it by --- JOIN table2 t2 ON  t1.reg = t2.reg where t2.tg IN (t1.tg1, t1.tg2, t1.tg3), this worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.tg IN (t1.tg1, t1.tg2, t1.tg3)
              AND t1.reg = t2.reg
-- WHERE t1.it = 1234
```